# How does reverse leakage current of a Schottky diode come into play with a SMPS?

Tags: voltage-regulator, diodes, switch-mode-power-supply, schottky

Looking at diodes for a low power switch-mode power supply I'm designing. I'm not quite sure what the reverse leakage current value is, or if it's relevant in the component selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Schottky diodes are great for SMPS applications because they have no reverse recovery. (Some Schottkys at higher voltage have guard ring structures that can cause some reverse recovery-like behavior.)  However, they do exhibit higher leakage current than conventional diodes, especially as the applied voltage increases.

The only downside of the extra leakage is a loss in efficiency.  If the supply is to operate at high temperatures, and the input voltage is relatively high for a Schottky diode the leakage loss can be significant enough to warrant investigation.

In general, people use Schottkys in switchers without even worrying about it.

Answer (score 5):

In general the leakage current at a given temperature will be higher for a lower voltage rated Schottky diode and higher for a higher current rated diode.

It's a trade-off because the forward losses go in the opposite direction in both cases.

For example, the SB560 5A diode - the digits after the 5 are the voltage rating- see that the leakage is less for higher voltage ratings, but forward voltage is more:

[image]

If you compare similar numbers with the 1A rated 1N5819, the leakage is 10mA at 100C, so it may not pay to use a diode with much higher ratings than required.

For example, suppose you wanted to minimize forward conduction losses and picked a SMT [STPS30L30DJF](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/DM00050888.pdf) 30V 30A Schottky for a 0.8A application. It's physically big (5mm x 6mm), but not insanely so, and has a forward drop of only a few hundred mV at 25°C and less than 150mV at 125°C. So the forward losses are only about 1/4W at 0.8A (when 'on'). However the reverse leakage at -20V is typically 60mA, so it would dissipate 1.2W when 'off' from reverse leakage. Probably not a net gain. A [1N5819](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/datasheets/1n5817.pdf) with 0.55V Vf would have 0.44W losses at 0.8A and 50mW reverse losses at -20V (2.5mA typical leakage). At 50% duty cycle, the losses would be 425mW for the 30A Schottky and 245mW for the 1A Schottky.